# Raspberry pi5 power supply

Tags: adafruit

Can I configure a GPIO pin to act as a 5V power supply? I need to use both 5V power supply pins to power my display.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No - you can't configure a GPIO pin as a 5V supply pin.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your display will run on  <16mA (and will accept <5V) it may work.

You claim "I need to use both 5V power supply pins to power my display" - WHY? You won't get any more current than a single pin.